# Relation between Pontryagin classes and Chern classes, confusion with proof

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I am trying to prove the following from Milnor and Stasheff but haven't been able to crack it. The hint seems to suggest that this can be done completely using the total chern classes but I haven't been able to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

All that’s going on here is the isomorphism
$$\omega_{\Bbb R} \otimes\Bbb C \cong \omega\oplus\overline\omega$$
and the fact that $c(E\oplus F)=c(E)c(F)$.

Comment: You mean $\omega_\mathbb{R}\otimes\mathbb{C}$, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Typing math on my iPad because of the coronavirus. :(

Comment: No worries. Keep your head up!